# Change PlaceHolders visibility on timer tick

Tags: c#, asp.net, placeholder

I'm writing a dashboard that is set to run by itself on a TV screen. I am fairly new to asp.net (normally do php) so simply I have 3 place holders which I would like to roll through on a asp timer. I am trying to do this through the visibility attribute on a placeholder. I'm currently having trouble getting it to actually roll through on the timer I think I need some way to pass back the values to the code behind but I am unsure of how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: The `onpage_load` works fine (showing panel1) and the first `tick_event` also works (hides panel1 and shows panel2) but then I get stuck at panel 2 and the page does not move from there.

Page

```
<asp:Content ID="MainContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div class='container_12' id='content'>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPmaincontent" runat="server" visible="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>   
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="Panel1" visible="false" runat="server"> 
                    <div class='grid_12' id='Emailbreakdown'>
                    </div>
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="Panel2" visible="false" runat="server">   
                    <div class='grid_12' id='WObreakdown'>
                    </div>
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="Panel3" visible="false" runat="server">
                    <div class='grid_12' id='IRbreakdown'>
                    </div>
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
         </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>  
    <div class='clear'>&nbsp;</div>   
<asp:Timer ID="Tmaincontent" runat="server" Interval="10000" OnTick="Tmaincontent_Tick"></asp:Timer>
</div>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel1.Visible = true;
    Panel2.Visible = false;
    Panel3.Visible = false;
}
public void Tmaincontent_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Panel1.Visible == true)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = false;
        Panel2.Visible = true;
        Panel3.Visible = false;
        UPmaincontent.Update();
    }
    else if (Panel2.Visible == true)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = false;
        Panel2.Visible = false;
        Panel3.Visible = true;
        UPmaincontent.Update();
    }
    else
    {
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        Panel2.Visible = false;
        Panel3.Visible = false;
        UPmaincontent.Update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.  The timer code and everything works properly, but remember that it's going to cause a PostBack event each time the timer fires and that causes the `Page_OnLoad` method to fire before the `Tmaincontent_Tick` thus resetting your panels each time.  Basically, you're stuck in a loop where Panel1 is always set to Visible and then Panel2 is set to Visible, so it can never get to three.

Here's the simple fix:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
        return;

    Panel1.Visible = true;
    Panel2.Visible = false;
    Panel3.Visible = false;
}


public void Tmaincontent_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Panel1.Visible)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = false;
        Panel2.Visible = true;
        Panel3.Visible = false;
        UPmaincontent.Update();
        return;
    }

    if (Panel2.Visible)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = false;
        Panel2.Visible = false;
        Panel3.Visible = true;
        UPmaincontent.Update();
        return;
    }

    Panel1.Visible = true;
    Panel2.Visible = false;
    Panel3.Visible = false;
    UPmaincontent.Update();

}
```

Comment: I tried your solution didn't seem to work (tried is a few different ways) as I have been able to roll from the on_page load (showing panel1) to the Tick event (which hid panel1 and showed panel2) then it would just stay at panel 2 and stop there in a loop.

Comment: I'll revise my answer and post the full code that I used.  It was just slightly optimized, but it did have a change to the if/else structure, so that might have done it.

Comment: Actually, your code for the OnTick event is ok (I just tested it).  You added the two lines to the OnLoad event, correct?

Comment: THANKS for you help that did it, now found that something else is breaking it.